# First time user getting "This looks like spam" when trying to post

Tags: bug, spam

I tried posting my question here (which I thought was the correct place to post false positives for spam) but it tells me that it looks like spam here too.

**EDIT** After posting the above simple post, I was able to post my entire post below. Should this be how I post my original question?

I tried editing my question and remove links to some of my research outside the stack overflow site, but I still get error. It's gotten to the point of removing useful information to try to make my post shorter.

> **Question Title**: If I change my MX records to point to Google Apps, will my email start going to my existing gmail account?
>
> **Body**: I currently forward my business e-mail to my gmail account (I send and receive business e-mail under my business e-mail, but from within gmail). I also use the gmail address itself for personal use. I like having all my e-mail in one gmail account (aka I don't really want to have two separate gmail accounts). I would like to switch my current business email to a google apps account.
>
> Over the years I have deleted a lot of email off my business email server (it's hosted by 1and1) because the 10-20mb attachments I receive from my customers adds up to the 2gb limit quite quickly. All that email is stored in my gmail account and it is very useful to have around (I dig up stuff from 3+ years ago for reference from time to time).
>
> My question is: If I change my domain MX record per the Google Apps instructions (https://apps.google.com/faq/setup/) will my email just magically start going to my existing gmail account? Will no migration be necessary since I already forward all my email to my existing gmail account? While I do have other accounts at the same domain name (one for each of my two employees) they are not heavily used and they can suffer a little bit of interrupted service, but I'd like my email to continue flowing as well as possible during the migration.
>
> I have a searched around a bit but I'm having particular trouble phrasing this search (which I assume is a very very common case) and getting good results. 5+ years of finding awesome answers on stack overflow and I've never had to ask a question because I've been able to find the answer. If this question has been answered before, I'd love to know how it was found (to improve my google-fu). One search phrase used was 'migrating from "forwarding to gmail" to "google apps for business"'.
>
> Here's what I've found related (and why it doesn't quite answer my question):
>
> [Selective mail migration Gmail > Google Apps](https://serverfault.com/questions/643470/selective-mail-migration-gmail-google-apps?newreg=0c7ed25e6e7a44379146d7c51ac2d3c7) (forwarding gmail account to a business account)
>
> [Migrating from Gmail to Google Apps](https://serverfault.com/questions/153373/migrating-from-gmail-to-google-apps) (this question seems quite related but it seems that they were using gmail in the first place, and not forwarding to gmail from a third party provider. I suppose they are also changing email addresses from user@gmail.com to user@company.com and creating entirely new gmail accounts).

Comment: Where were you planning on asking this.  Asking for my dog.

Answer (score 1):

There are several 'issues' with your post which may trigger the spam filter. For example, you have an email address in it, a link to the Google App Store. If you leave those out, it probably won't fail.

Indeed, this is a false positive, and unfortunately nothing on your side you can change. Maybe the team can lift the filter for a second so you can post your question, or alter the filter a little to the false positive won't occur.